# Perl converting GET to POST

Tags: html, perl, web-applications, http-post

I have built a web application that passes all form input data through the URL. Can someone help me figure out how to send data using POST instead? I am starting to handle large amounts of data, and GET creates an issue with the URL being too long. If there is a simple JavaScript way to do this, I'd be interested as well.

For example, the input form has an attribute called `txtName` and the user has typed `John`.  On the new form, I need it to get `John` and assign it to the variable `$Name` using the POST method.

Right now I'm using GET and am chomping the parameters to get the data out of the URL.

How do you, in Perl, get POST to work on both forms?

I changed GET to POST on the form submitting data. On the form receiving data I put

```
use HTTP::Request::Common qw(POST);
use LWP::UserAgent; 

$ua = LWP::UserAgent->new;
```

at the top, then under that I put

```
my req = POST 'http://intranet/webservice/enhancements/ManagementEnhancementPerson.pl',
      [ $Person ='person' ];
```

The web page is the page I'm taking data from, `$Person` is the variable I want it to be, and `person` is the name of the input on the original form.

I've been stuck on this for a while. I'm relatively new to Perl and web development.

Here are my use statements at the top of the page *receiving* the data.

```
use CGI::Carp 'fatalsToBrowser';
use warnings;

use Net::SMTP;
use HTTP::Request::Common qw(POST);
use LWP::UserAgent;

$ua = LWP::UserAgent->new;
```

Comment: You still have all the same obscurities as your earlier questions. You're asking how *you* can send data, but you won't be around do to anything. You say the form gets and assigns, but forms can't perform actions. Your language is still very unclear. Also, the programming language is called "Perl", not "PERL".

Comment: @jm666, It doesn't make much sense to say a question is a duplicate of a closed question. Furthermore, I suggested he post his clarified question as a new question rather than fixing a buried and closed question. Unfortunately, he did a bad job of it. :(

Comment: I guess I don't know how to make it better... Essentially I just want to know how to convert the get process to the post process on each of the two forms.

Comment: You need to start by specifying what framework, if any, you have used to build your application. Are you using Dancer, Catalyst, or something similar? If you don't understand the question then just say what `use` statements you have at the top of your program. Better still, post your code here so that we can see for ourselves.

Comment: OK, I'll add to the question description.

Comment: Your understanding of the concepts is wrong. The *forms* are just HTML pages running on web clients - browsers. If you are using `LWP` then you are writing a program *pretending* to be a browser, and sending data that would normally be typed into a browser form. The *web application* is the thing running on the *server*. The only place you seem to mention it is in the URL you use. What is in `ManagementEnhancementPerson.pl`? Do you have `use CGI` anywhere?

Comment: Having a variable variable name makes no sense.

Comment: ManagementEnhancementPerson.pl is the Web page that people are viewing, and it contains perl script. There are input options for people to type in, and those values need to be sent to EnhancementManagementUpdate people using POST.

Comment: So, ManagementEnhancementUpdate.pl contains those use statements I posted in the question.

Comment: @ikegami I just need the variable in the second form to contain the name that the user types in on the first form.

Comment: @Justin: The problem is that the POST or GET requests should be coming from the browser (or from a program pretending to be a browser). You shouldn't have them in a CGI program on the server side like `ManagementEnhancementPerson.pl`. Were they in there before you added them?

Comment: Yes, I've been using get in all the forms. We have an existing Web application that uses get for all data processing.

Comment: @Jsutin: To put it another way, HTTP is a client-server protocol, where the client sends *requests*, like GET, POST, HEAD, and a few others, which commonly contain the data entered into an HTML form, and the server sends back *responses* to the client, which generally contain the HTML page for a new page to display. By adding a POST request to your `ManagementEnhancementPerson.pl` file you are trying to make it work as both a server *and* a client, and if you manage to send your POST successfully the response will go back to the *server's* IP address, and not to the browser.

Comment: @Justin: But web servers (which is where web applications run) don't use GET because they don't make HTTP requests at all - they just send responses.

Comment: We really can't help you at all without sight of *all* of what you're written. I can't begin to imagine what you've done at present.

Comment: I'd show you, but my employer won't let me login to forums.. So I have to use the app on my phone to post. Literally I put the method to "POST" on the perl page sending the data (ManagementEnhancementPerson.pl) and I just need to know what to put on the perl page receiving the data (ManagementEnhancementUpdate.pl)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you make the request using the following (slightly altered from what you posted to make sense):

```
my $request = POST 'http://.../ManagementEnhancementPerson.pl', [
   person => $Person,
];

my $response = $ua->request($request);
```

You would extract the value using the following in `ManagementEnhancementPerson.pl`:

```
use CGI qw( );
my $cgi = CGI->new;
my $Person = $cgi->param('person');
```

The CGI module provides the form data via `param` regardless of whether the form was submitted using `GET` or `POST`.

Comment: Thanks for your help.. Would I put both of those sets of code in ManagementEnhancementPerson.pl page? Or does one go in ManagementEnhancementUpdate.pl (form receiving data) and the other go in ManagementEnhancementPerson.pl (form sending the data)?

Comment: This comment is so full of errors. 1) Forms don't receive data. 2) `ManagementEnhancementUpdate.pl` isn't a form. 3) `ManagementEnhancementUpdate.pl` is the one receiving the data in your question. 4) My answer already says where to place the code.

Comment: OK, thanks a lot for your help. I'll play with that code and try to make it work. Thanks for answering through all my crap!